execution error in javascript post event $.post when in dev everything is ok
My javascript code raise an error in my production server (nginx+gunicorn) when all is ok in dev.
here is my js
many thanks for your help
<script>
        const findLoc = () => {
             const success = (position) => {
                const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                const longitude = position.coords.longitude; 
                var data = {'latitude': latitude,
                            'longitude': longitude };
                data.csrfmiddlewaretoken = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
                console.log('Location is on');
                console.log(data);
                document.getElementById("LocationLat").innerHTML = latitude;
                document.getElementById("LocationLon").innerHTML = longitude;
                ----->$.post("gps/", data,function(response) {
                            // La réponse est maintenant disponible dans la variable 'response'
                            console.log('Réponse reçue:', response);
                            document.getElementById("postdata").innerHTML = response;
                            $('.spinner-border').hide();
                            
                        // Faites quelque chose avec les données, par exemple mettre à jour le contenu de la page
                        }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                            // En cas d'échec de la requête, affichez l'erreur
                            console.log('Erreur lors de la requête:', status, error);
             });
            }
    
            const error = () => {
                console.log('Location gathering Not allowed')
                $('.spinner-border').hide();
                document.getElementById("postdata").innerHTML ="Activate position in your browser !"
            }
    
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,error);
        }
        
      </script>

the error is raised by this instruction ---->$.post
here the console in the browser :
enter image description here
urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('gps/',views.home_view),

views.py
def home_view(request):   

        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR') 

        if request.method == 'POST':
            Latitude = float(request.POST.get('latitude'))
            Longitude = float(request.POST.get('longitude'))
            context = aviationweatherapi.getStationInfo(None,Latitude,Longitude)
            print ("Get airports list around current GPS location")
            #print (context)
            templateview='partial-results.html'
            
        
        else:
             #The request is GET
             list ='LFHC,LFHN,LFHS,LFJD,LFKY'
             context = aviationweatherapi.getStationInfo(list, None, None)
             context.update({'IP':ip})
             print ("Get all airports")
             templateview='acceuil.html'
        
        context.update({'IP':ip})

        return render(request,templateview,context)

i hope resolve this error because without response data from my view anything is displayed

1). Check the prod backend logs for any clues, you may have some django security settings missing. 2) Make sure you're accessing url via https

Hi thanks for  your help, indeed the problem in production came from nginx configuration file for my web site. now i add the last parameter in the section location : location / {
proxy_pass              http://localhost:8000;
proxy_set_header        Host $host;
proxy_set_header        X_FORWARDED_FOR $remote_addr;
---->  proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

thanks for your help,
here is my solution to use ajax post request in production env.
Indeed the problem in production came from nginx configuration file for my web site. now i add the last parameter in the section location :
location / {
    proxy_pass              http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X_FORWARDED_FOR $remote_addr;
  ---->  proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

